# Angular code splitting into multiple functional bundles

Tags: angular, angular7, bundling-and-minification, code-splitting, tree-shaking

Angular 7. How to split code into multiple functional bundle files.
I want to generate multiple bundle files:

*) Chunk1 / bundle 1

```
- component 1
- component 2
```

*) Chunk2 / bundle 2

```
- component 3
- component 4
```

Is there any other way of doing this apart from [Lazy loading components](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: As of now LAZY LOADING is the only way available for creating chunks.

It makes one module independent of other modules.

Comment: Angular compiles components via modules. I don't think it's possible for components to exist without a module. How modules are bundled is handled by web pack. If you want a different bundle structure from what the CLI can do, then you need a custom web pack configuration.